# Strange: Too many values to unpack, but I've got the right anmount

Tags: python

Getting this error:

```
File "g:\My Drive\CNN_LSTM-Multioutput_python.py", line 192, in <module>
    windowed_dataset_validation, labels_validation = create_window_dataset_multi(cross_validation_dataset_normalized, cross_validation_dataset[:, -1*y_len:], WINDOW_SIZE, y_labels, dataset.columns), ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Where my function returns two numpy arrays: windowed_dataset, labels_dataset

And the function is defined as:

```
def create_window_dataset_multi(ds, lb, window_size, y_labels, dataset_cols):
    windowed_dataset = []
    labels_dataset = []

    for y_index, y in enumerate(y_labels):
        x_dataset = []
        labels = []

        x_index = dataset_cols.get_loc(y[:-2])
        x_ds = np.delete(ds, x_index, 1)

        for i in range(window_size, x_ds.shape[0] + 1):
            x_dataset.append(x_ds[i - window_size:i])
            labels.append(lb[i - 1])
        
        windowed_dataset.append(x_dataset)
        labels_dataset.append(labels)


    return np.array(windowed_dataset), np.array(labels_dataset)
```

I have debugged the code, and I can see it distinctively returns two items, why is it throwing this error? Debug shown below.

[image]

Comment: So if you do something like `blah = create_window_dataset_multi(whatever, etc, ...)`, what are the contents of `blah` after? It should be a list or tuple with two items in it; those items being `ndarray`s.

Comment: Blah is a tuple of two tuples...

Comment: So it's like `((item1,),(item2))`, right? What are the `item`s within the tuples? Regardless, you should be able to do `windowed_dataset_validation, labels_validation = blah` with no issue, right? Because if you do that, the type of those two variables should be `tuple`.

Comment: Nevermind: blah is equal to
((array([[[[0.63446201...25579]]]]), array([[[  2.369 ,  ...9.5   ]]])),)

Comment: How do I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Found the problem, was a comma at the end. FML.